# How to tether an old Android 2.1 phone with the Asus Transformer

Tags: tethering, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I want to tether my Samsung Europia to my Asus Transformer so I can use my phone 3g connection.

Is this possible? The Samsung doesn't have native tethering built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally for the samsung Europia, a free update can be downloaded via Kies to upgrade to android 2.2. This then allows you to natively turn your phone into a wifi hotspot. It's then the usual connect to wifi affair

Answer (score 1):

Is your phone rooted?  If so, try using the [WiFi Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) app.  You will need to download the APK and side-load it.